# What is the difference between form_for and remote_form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi can anyone tell when to use form_for and remote_form_for in Ruby on rails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remote_form_for is a helper used in rails 2.x (maybe 1.x too) to create a form, that should be submitted via AJAX.

`form_for` is a rails 3 helper. You can pass it `:remote => true` parameter if you want the form to be submitted via AJAX. AFAIK Rails 3.x doesn't have the `remote_form_for` helper anymore.

**updated**

you use form_for to create a form for a resource. Like `form_for Article.new` - it will automatically map the form to the `post articles/` route.

`form_tag` is used to create general forms.

Comment: form_tag is used if you want to point the form action to a URL. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag